# Where can I ask a question regarding an error installing Doxygen?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I tried to install Doxygen from the binary distribution for Ubuntu Linux x86-64. It throws up an error regarding `libclang.so.6`. I wanted to know where exactly on SE do I ask how to fix the error in more detail. Now Doxygen is a documentation generating tool for various languages (C++, C, Fortran etc) but I'll be using it to document a set of physics programs. So does my question belong on Stack Overflow, Super User, Computational Science, or somewhere else entirely? I'm a novice user.

I can supply more details about the error in the comments, but I think this is enough information for a site recommendation.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm using Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dedicated [Ubuntu Q&A site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/) that has a [doxygen](/questions/tagged/doxygen) [tag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/doxygen). It also has a [software-instalation](/questions/tagged/software-instalation) [tag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-installation)

As always check the [site's help centre](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) before asking, but it does say

> Development on Ubuntu.

is on-topic, so I expect that a question on installing a development tool would be OK.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out right away.

Comment: It would also be on-topic on [su].

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill. I asked [the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008306/doxygen-cannot-find-the-shared-librarys-libclang-so-6-version-llvm-6-0-wh) on Ask Ubuntu, with the tags suggested above by Robert Longson. However, it's been 2 days, but I haven't received any answers. I think I better ask on Super User too. The rules say that asking the same question on multiple SE sites is forbidden, but given that I haven't received answers on Ask Ubuntu, may I post the same question to Super User without closing the question in Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: You can ask the Ubuntu mods to migrate to su

Comment: @RobertLongson sorry I was late in marking your answer as 'accepted' - I'm new to this :P

Comment: @DavidPostill - What is the standard procedure to ask mods to migrate question to other site? Flag as "in need of moderator intervention" and insert "migrate" request there? Or is there another way?

Comment: @Sreyam Yes. Exactly that.

Comment: @Sreyam yes, flag for moderation and explain clearly what you want to happen. The moderators will contact their peers on superuser and migrate if the superuser moderators agree. Or alternatively delete it on Ubuntu and then ask on superuser yourself. Doing it yourself would likely be quicker.

Comment: @DavidPostill and Robert Longson - thanks, both of you have been very helpful. I'll wait 24 hours, and if the mods haven't contacted me by then I'll retract the flag, delete the question and ask it on SU.